# How to achieve the same function of views.py through extention of clean method of forms?

Tags: python, django

My views.py

```
class CreateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
model = Task
form_class = TaskForm
template_name = 'tasks/form.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(CreateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
    ctx['action'] = 'Add'
    ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.list')
    return ctx


def form_valid(self, form):

    form.save(self.request.user)
    messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been created.'))
    return redirect('tasks.list')


class UpdateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
model = Task
form_class = TaskForm
template_name = 'tasks/form.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(UpdateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
    ctx['action'] = 'Update'
    ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.detail', args=[self.get_object().id])
    return ctx

def form_valid(self, form):

    form.save(self.request.user)


    messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been updated.'))
    return redirect('tasks.list')
```

My forms.py

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
keywords = (forms.CharField(
            help_text=_('Please use commas to separate your keywords.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'medium-field'})))
admin_time = forms.IntegerField(
            help_text=_('Enter If more than 60 minutes.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance']:
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial['keywords'] = kwargs['instance'].keywords_list
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def _process_keywords(self, creator):
    if 'keywords' in self.changed_data:
        kw = [k.strip() for k in self.cleaned_data['keywords'].split(',')]
        self.instance.replace_keywords(kw, creator)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))

    return cleaned_data



def save(self, creator, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance.creator = creator
    super(TaskForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('commit', True):
        self._process_keywords(creator)
    return self.instance



class Media:
    css = {
        'all': ('css/admin_ace.css',)
    }

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'execution_time', 'difficulty',
              'priority', 'repeatable', 'team', 'project', 'type', 'start_date',
              'end_date', 'why_this_matters', 'prerequisites', 'instructions',
              'is_draft', 'is_invalid')
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'short_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'instructions': AceWidget(mode='markdown', theme='textmate', width='800px',
                                  height='300px', wordwrap=True,
                                  attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'start_date': CalendarInput,
        'end_date': CalendarInput,
        'why_this_matters': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'prerequisites': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
    }
```

I want to extend the clean method in forms.py and do a validation before the form get processed.

That is, I tried this- but it doesnt' work :(

```
  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))

    execution_time = cleaned_data.get('execution_time')
    if cleaned_data.get('admin_time'):


        self.instance.execution_time = cleaned_data.get('admin_time')
    return cleaned_data
```

What I want to achieve is, if admin_time is present, then execution_time should be equal to admin_time.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck a this place.

What I did first was I 
in CreateTaskView added like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
  task_object = form.save(self.request.user, commit=False)
  admin_time = form.cleaned_data['admin_time']
  if admin_time:
    task_object.execution_time=admin_time
    task_object.save(self.request.user)
    messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been created.'))
    return redirect('tasks.list')
```

and in UpdateTaskView

```
def form_valid(self, form):
  admin_time = form.cleaned_data.get('admin_time')
  if admin_time:
    self.object.execution_time = admin_time
    self.object.save()
  form.save(self.request.user)
  messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been updated.'))
  return redirect('tasks.list')
```

This code worked- but duplication of the same function in two classes need to be removed. Can I do this as extention of clean method of forms.py and get the same functionality done? That is if admin_time is entered in form entry it should replace executable_time=admin_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean methods should only be used for form validation. Since setting the execution time to be the same as the admin time has nothing to do with validation, I think putting it in the views is the appropriate place. Why not just create a Mixin to do it for you and then have both your CreateTaskView and UpdateTaskView consume that mixin?

```
class SetExecutionTime(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
       self.object = form.save(self.request.user, commit=False)
       admin_time = form.cleaned_data['admin_time']
       if admin_time:
         self.object.execution_time = admin_time
         self.object.save()
       form.save(self.request.user)
       # do your success message/redirect here
```

THen you can just consume the mixin like:

```
class UpdateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, SetExecutionTime, generic.UpdateView)
```

Comment: I want this redirect:
    return redirect('tasks.list')

Comment: How can i make my updatetaskview and createtaskview consume this mixing? by passing it in? that will do?

Comment: Yep, just consume it like any other mixin that you already consuming.

Comment: I added this class in mixin, and then in 
class UpdateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, SetExecutionTime, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
I added SetExecutionTime like this. Not sure how else to make the function work.

Comment: I had added SetExecution Time to the function()
But it doesn't update the value! Is there anything more left to be done, add in some more line or anything?

Comment: Have you updated the form_valid methods in your UpdateTaskView? If you still have those form_valids defined as they are in the original question, it won't call the mixin. You should be able to just remove those implementation's of form_valid completely, and just put all the login you need in your new mixin.

Comment: you mean def form_valid(self, form):
        
        form.save(self.request.user)


    
        messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been updated.'))
        return redirect('tasks.list')

Comment: Yes. If your success message/redirect url needs to be different in each view you could define a success_message/success_url attribute on the class and then reference them.

Comment: yes I got it working :) removed both the functions!! Thanks a lot Tareq!! :)